# Add a day to a week in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question. So my code is :

```
SELECT *
   FROM table
WHERE (WEEK(`end`)=26 + INTERVAL 1 DAY) and YEAR(`end`)=2016
```

The idea is to add to the week a day. I don't now if it's possible. Please help me

Comment: ok what exactly do you want to do?  This is in a where statement.  Please describe which records you want to filter.  For example -- "I want all records where the date field END falls in the 25th week of the year" or "I want the Monday after the week the date field END falls in to be the 25th day of the month."  These are my two guesses at what the heck you are trying to do.

Comment: The idea is to set the week in sql to get data from `Monday` not from `Sunday`

Comment: @HareaCosticla -- that is part of the week function as Tim points out.

Comment: The Gregorian calendar has 7 days in a week, you cannot add more days to it, unless you create a new calendar, which mysql does not support (afaik). I do not understand your problem. Your question does not contain a question. Please edit your question to include an actual question as well as more details of what you have tried as well as any errors you may be getting.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WEEK()` along with a mode to choose what the first day of the week is:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE WEEK(`end`, 1) = 26 AND YEAR(`end`) = 2016
```

[MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)